# .htaccess redirect. Prioritize one rule over another

Tags: .htaccess

I have two rules on .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

1)RewriteRule ^simple_api/api/([a-zA-Z]+)  /simple_api/api.php?mode=$1 [QSA]

2)# Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to index.php.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I want rule number 1 to have priority over rule number 2, but right now number 2 is always in effect and rule number 1 is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the flags for the first rule from `[QSA]` to `[QSA,L]`

That will make sure that Rule processing will stop when Rule 1 matches.  You may also want to put in a `RewriteCond` for Rule 1 to make sure that it doesn't catch everything.